# Starcraft II Practicing new units and game changes

Tags: starcraft-2

Since Legacy of the Void the challenge missions are banned to the terran campaign "Episode I Wings of Lilberty", followed by the Challenge Missions image.

These missions still use the game settings for WoL.

Are there similar Challenges available to practise your skills with the new LotV rules and units? Maybe somewhere in the Arcade section, something like [Starcraft Masters](http://battlenet://starcraft/map/2/110670)?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to:

**Watch Streams**: Watch some of the best SC2 streamers. Of course, watch the players which play your race. You'll see how to use new tricky units and which build to learn in order to build them. Take a look at [Twitch SC2](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/StarCraft%20II) and [Team Liquid Stream Wall](http://www.teamliquid.net/);

**Play custom games with friends or vs AI**: You'll be able to test new units without failing or being stressed;

**Play Micro Arena - Arcade**: You'll be only focused on using a bunch of units to win. You will learn, also, how to use some of the new units or just combine them with the old ones;

**Play Unit Tester - Arcade**: You'll be able to create any army you want and test every unit and its ability;

**Play Unranked and Ranked Games**: When you'll be a bit more confident, try starting to climb the ladder;

**Play off-race games**: Try playing with all 3 different races to understand deeply how new units work.

I hope I've been Helpful.